# Control-M :How to Iterate one Child Step of an hourly Cyclic Job

Tags: java, control-m

I am new to Control M and have this below scenario to Implement.

Cyclic Job A(Runs every 1 hour)

Step1 : Runs a Webservice call to initiate a program.

Step2:  Runs a Webservice which checks status of the Program kicked off by Step 1.Returns "Complete" or "Waiting"
          (This is to be made cyclic,say make it run every 2 minutes until the next Iteration begins or Until output Parameter of Step 2 reads value "Complete")

Step3: When Step 2 returns Complete, this step should be invoked.

Can you please tell me if this can be achieved in Ctrl M and how?

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the Control-M version you are using?
2. What type of a job is Job A?
3. Where are you defining the 3 steps?
4. Why are you trying to perform 3 steps with different scheduling criteria in a single job?

Comment: Control M Version - 9.
If I can rephrase, I want to invoke a webservice call as Step 1 and once the call is complete perform Step 2. As the remote program takes more than an hours to complete, I wanted to know if I can split the Webservice Call to a step which just does invocation( remote prog is made to run asynchronous) and then run second job every 2 min to check status , instead of keeping the thread open for an hour. Then based on Step 2 response continue with the subsequent Jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your Step 2 job post a condition on Complete that is an In condition for job Step 3. Once the condition is posted, the third job exec requirements will be satisfied, and it will get executed.